# My class got deleted after i saved and closeed

Tags: java, switch-statement

After i saved my class while i was working on it last night, it got deleted this morning. I am sure its not corrupted since i am sure i saved it and closed it right. I already tried restore from local history. I also searched google and i found no help...
i worked hard on the class, i really don't want to code it again.[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcEhI.png)
The other classes are fine and they have evreything from last night. its just my main...

UPDATE:
Sorry for posting this here, my bad. I was just really pissed cuz half my code got deleted. Anyways here's some real help i need... Before my code got deleted my Computer Science teacher helped me write the `switch` code for my main. Now that it's deleted i need some help from you guy's!!! I need my input to be able to read Chars and Int's. This is what i have so far...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


    do {
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter your birthYear");
            birthYear = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
            int length = String.valueOf(birthYear).length();
            System.out.println(length);
            if (length != 4) {
                lengthTest = false;
                System.out.println("Invalid Choice");
            } else {
                lengthTest = true;

            }
            test = true;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Invalid Choice");
        }

    } while (test == true ^ lengthTest != false);
    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1-4 \n"
                + "1 = AreaOfTriangle \n" + 
                "----------------------------------\n" + 
                "2 = HoursToDaysAndHours Calculator \n" + 
                "---------------------------------- \n" + 
                "3 = CelciusToFahrenheit Calculator \n" + 
                "----------------------------------\n" + 
                "4 = BirthdayGame \r\n" + 
                "----------------------------------");



        try {
            choice = (char)Integer.parseInt(input.next().toLowerCase());
            System.out.println(choice);
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            aOT.areaOfTriangle();
            break;
        case 2:
            hTDAH.hoursToDaysAndHours();
            break;
        case 3:
            cTF.celciusToFahrenheit();
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Code not implemented yet");
            break;
        case 'e':
            repeat = false;
            break;
            default:
                System.out.println("This part of the program has not been implemented");
                break;
        } 
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Awnser");
        }

    } while (repeat == true);

}
```

Comment: _i worked hard on the class.._ This is where versioning and back-ups get very important!

Comment: That's unfortunate. I'm not sure it constitutes a question.

Comment: Well, take this opportunity to turn this misfortune into a positive. Learn to use version control. Set up a GitHub profile and push your work there periodically. You'll never lose work again.

Comment: @khelwood i know but its weird how i saved and it didnt really save so it bothers me alot. Then i think i have no choice to retype the code. Its just so weird how Eclipse just dosn't want to save sometimes. This happend to me 3 or              4 times before so its just really sketchy.

Comment: @Michael i have github but i dont use it often. il start using it now...

Comment: Did you happen to compile the new calc.java at all ? If you did then you could locate calc.class and just decompile it and take the code from there... (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Decompiler)

Comment: @mkane I did, its fine now i rewrote the code no biggie...

Comment: @mkane i was going to decompile it but i was in a rush this morning so i didn't and just rewrote the whole code...

Comment: Your current code doesn't compile. If you need help fixing compilation errors then please state what error message on what line you need help with.

Comment: @Eelke it does compile. I just left out the variables and class name cus it didnt let me format the code on StackOverflow

Comment: Please provide [minimal and complete code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it is difficult to help you when we you add additional problems to your code by leaving important stuff out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should setup a version control system e.g. [Git](https://git-scm.com/). To quote Attlasian [What is version control](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/what-is-version-control) page:

> Version control systems are a category of software tools that help a software team manage changes to source code over time. Version control software keeps track of every modification to the code in a special kind of database. If a mistake is made, developers can turn back the clock and compare earlier versions of the code to help fix the mistake while minimizing disruption to all team members.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a featured to get ancient version of a file i think,

https://hls.harvard.edu/dept/its/restoring-previous-versions-of-files-and-folders/

try this maybe. GL

Comment: note that if you didn't save anything it wont work

Comment: @ Aurele Collinet that didnt work. Its fine tho i will just rewrite it. I learned from my mistakes...